# Regex for password validation with optional special characters from specific set

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to figure out how to make special char. (selected ones only) optional in following regex:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[[\]{};:=<>_+^#$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d[\]{};:=<>_+^#$@$!%*?&]{8,30}
```

Above regex checking if there is at least 1 number, 1 uppercase, 1 lower case and 1 special character from this set: [[]{};:=<>+^#$@$!%*?&

Now I try to make special char. optional but if supplied it should be from the allowed set and all other conditions (1 uppercase, 1 number, 1 lower case) should match. Any idea, how to make that work?

Comment: Just remove `(?=.*[[\]{};:=<>_+^#$@$!%*?&])` from your regex

Comment: Now when it works, It feels like that's what I did before but ended up in some error. Just one of those days.

Comment: Don't limit it this way. You think you're making the passwords more secure, but you're not. You're telling any hackers that everyone's passwords contain specific character sets. People can't use a password such as `é123#Ç12` because `é` is not recognized as a lowercase letter and `Ç` is not recognized as an uppercase letter. The result: a user would maybe change it to `e123#C12` which is much less secure. Do the password validation server-side. Anything implemented client-side can be manipulated.

Comment: @ctwheels, thanks I understand what you mean, but in this case, it's very closed application and there are more layers of validation involved server side and also at database level. Also this is only for changing the password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just remove this lookahead from your regex:

```
(?=.*[[\]{};:=<>_+^#@$!%*?&])
```

This assertion enforce presence of at least one special character in your regex.

Your regex will become:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d[\]{};:=<>_+^#$@!%*?&]{8,30}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/weHdrZ/2)

Comment: Thanks, I did try that but somehow I made some typo somewhere. I was using Expresso and Regex101 tool at the same time.

Comment: `$` is in your set twice - I know you just copied OP's but should be cleaned up anyway.